# Laravel и Tarantool?

Tags: php, laravel, tarantool

Кто нибудь пользуется новой БД Tarantool ? говорят очень производительная, но официальный сайт ведет на библиотеку в гитхаб, где только можно использовать с php 5.x , но уже без php7 Никуда.
У нас стоит laravel, который работает минимум с 7.1.3

Может кто нибудь знает какие нибудь другие хорошие in memory bd в связке с laravel

Суть БД не в надежности, а в быстродействии и хранении данных типо кеша но с удобствами бд.
Данные в этой бд не страшно потерять, все действия применяются в Mysql.

Суть проекта такая, что все время в онлайне есть 300-500 заказов и устройств около 700, которые каждые 30 секунд шлют запросы на сервер типо "Есть ли для меня новые заказы", всю нагрузку на сервер создает в основном Mysql

это не интернет магазин, а это трекинговая система, тут все запросы по API с мобильных устройств

Comment: а что, `mysql` с индексированными запросами перестал справляться? Не поверю. Яб на вашем месте посмотрел бы в сторону `Reindexer`. Если у вас какие-то определенные запросы, то надо конкретно выбирать и подбирать БД, а не брать: "я слышал, что `Tarantool` норм и очень производительная"

Comment: Исходя из вашей задачи, вам нужен не Тарантул, а кэширующий сервер. Для этих целей достаточно **memcached**, который с *php* хорошо дружит

Comment: Нет времени анализировать, ставь Тарантула.

Comment: Все индексы настроены, без них нагрузка и так была большая, после индексов нагрузка упала процентов на 50%, но как я сказал выше, там 1400 запросов в бд, есть ли заказы для данного устройства. т.е большинство запросов идут в бд, когда там для них ничего нету. Я пробую сейчас с редисом, но не все так легко

Comment: Повторюсь, это не интернет магазин, а это трекинговая система

Answer (score 0):

Официальный коннектор поддерживает php 7.0-7.2 (7.3 пока [не поддерживается](https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool-php/issues/139)), ставить нужно из ветки php7-v2 (есть соответствующий [тикет](https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool-php/issues/137) о переименовании этой ветки в master).

Так же есть неофицильный клиент для 7.1+: https://github.com/tarantool-php/client.